# angular http interceptor repeat request doesn't work

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

i am doing angular 8 application and i am trying to implement angular http interceptor repeat request. I want intercept all my UI requests to WebAPI and when my token is expired, refresh the token and recall all requests which were rejected.
I implemented the code:

```
import { Inject, Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import {
    HttpInterceptor,
    HttpRequest,
    HttpResponse,
    HttpHandler,
    HttpEvent,
    HttpErrorResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable, throwError, from, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { StorageSvc } from '../factories/storageSvc';
import { SysSettings } from '../constant/sysSettings';
import { SingletonRootClass } from '../../../src/app/shared/singleton-root';
import { AuthService } from './authService';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()

export class InterceptService implements HttpInterceptor {

    refreshTokenInProgress = false;

    tokenRefreshedSource = new Subject();
    tokenRefreshed$ = this.tokenRefreshedSource.asObservable();


    constructor(@Inject(StorageSvc) public storageSvc: any,
                @Inject(AuthService) public authService: any,
                private router: Router,
                private injector: Injector
    ) { }

    addAuthHeader(request) {
        const authData = this.storageSvc.retrieve('authorizationData');
        const language = authData && authData.profile
            ? { languageCode: authData.profile.laguageCode, regionCode: authData.profile.regionCode }
            : this.getDefaultLanguage();

        const headers = {
            'Accept-Language': this.buildAcceptLanguageHeader(language.languageCode, language.regionCode),
            'NotificationConnectionId': SysSettings.NotifyConnectionId
        };

        if (authData) {
            headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + authData.token;
            headers['UserName'] = authData.userName;
        }

        request = request.clone({
            setHeaders: headers
        });

        return request;
    }

    // intercept request and add token
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<any> {
        request = this.addAuthHeader(request);

        // Handle response
        return next.handle(request).pipe(
            map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
                if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                    console.log('event--->>>', event);
                }
                return event;
            }),
                catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                    if (error.status === 401) {
                        return this.refreshToken()
                            .switchMap(() => {
                                request = this.addAuthHeader(request);
                                return next.handle(request);
                            })
                            .catch(() => {
                                this.authService.logOut();
                                this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                            });
                    }

                    return throwError(error);
                })
        );

    }

    refreshToken() {
        if (this.refreshTokenInProgress) {
            return new Observable(observer => {
                this.tokenRefreshed$.subscribe(() => {
                    observer.next();
                    observer.complete();
                });
            });
        } else {
            this.refreshTokenInProgress = true;

            return this.authService.refreshToken()
                .do(() => {
                    this.refreshTokenInProgress = false;
                    this.tokenRefreshedSource.next();
                });
        }
    }

    sleep(ms = 0) {
        return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));
    }
    getDefaultLanguage() {
        // const savedLanguage = this.storageSvc.retrieve('language');
        const savedLanguage = SingletonRootClass.getInstance().defaultLang;
        // Region code not used for now
        const language = { languageCode: savedLanguage ? savedLanguage : 'en', regionCode: 'CA' };
        return language;
    }

    buildAcceptLanguageHeader(languageCode, regionCode) {
        return languageCode + '-' + regionCode + ',' + languageCode + ';' + 'q=0.8,en;q=0.6';
    }
}
```

But I cannot recall automatically requests which were rejected. On my screenshot : GetNotifications, GetNotificationTypes and GetEventTypes

[image]

Could anyone recommend angular solution for interceptor to recall all requests which were rejected on the same time when token was refreshed?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
  isRefreshingToken: boolean = false;
  tokenSubject: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError((err, source) => {
        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          if (err.status === 401) {
            return this.handle401Error(request, next);
          } 
        }
        return observableThrowError(err.error);
      })
    );
  }

  private handle401Error(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<any> {
    this.requestRefreshToken();
    return this.tokenSubject.pipe(
      take(1),
      switchMap(token => {
        return next.handle(request);
      }));

  }

  private requestRefreshToken() {
    if (!this.isRefreshingToken) {
      this.isRefreshingToken = true;
      this.authService.refreshToken()
        .subscribe(user => {
          if (user) {
            this.tokenSubject.next(user);
          }
          this.isRefreshingToken = false;
        }, (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          this.authService.logout()
          this.isRefreshingToken = false; 
          return observableThrowError(err);
        }, () => {
        });
    }
  }
```

Comment: What did you change? What did you add? Comparing the question and answer letter by letter to get the difference is a bit too much.

Answer (score 0):

Interception solution which is working for me for Angular 7:

auth-interceptor.ts

```
import { Inject, Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import {
    HttpInterceptor,
    HttpRequest,
    HttpResponse,
    HttpHandler,
    HttpEvent,
    HttpErrorResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable, throwError, from, Subject, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { StorageSvc } from '../factories/storageSvc';
import { SysSettings } from '../constant/sysSettings';
import { SingletonRootClass } from '../../../src/app/shared/singleton-root';
import { AuthService } from './authService';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { take, switchMap  } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()

export class InterceptService implements HttpInterceptor {

    private isRefreshing = false;
    private refreshTokenSubject: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

    constructor(@Inject(StorageSvc) public storageSvc: any,
                @Inject(AuthService) public authService: any,
                private router: Router,
                private injector: Injector
    ) { }

    addAuthHeader(request) {
        const authData = this.storageSvc.retrieve('authorizationData');
        const language = authData && authData.profile
            ? { languageCode: authData.profile.laguageCode, regionCode: authData.profile.regionCode }
            : this.getDefaultLanguage();

        const headers = {
            'Accept-Language': this.buildAcceptLanguageHeader(language.languageCode, language.regionCode),
            'NotificationConnectionId': SysSettings.NotifyConnectionId
        };

        if (authData) {
            console.log("token:" + 'Bearer ' + authData.token);
            headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + authData.token;
            headers['UserName'] = authData.userName;
        }

        request = request.clone({
            setHeaders: headers
        });

        return request;
    }


    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<any> {

        request = this.addAuthHeader(request);

        return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(error => {
            if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && error.status === 401) {
                return this.handle401Error(request, next);
            } else {
                return throwError(error);
            }
        }));
    }

    private handle401Error(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
        if (!this.isRefreshing) {
            this.isRefreshing = true;
            this.refreshTokenSubject.next(null);

            return this.authService.refreshToken().pipe(
                switchMap((token: any) => {
                    this.isRefreshing = false;
                    this.refreshTokenSubject.next(token.access_token);
                    request = this.addAuthHeader(request);
                    return next.handle(request);
                }));

        } else {
            return this.refreshTokenSubject.pipe(
                filter(token => token != null),
                take(1),
                switchMap(jwt => {
                    request = this.addAuthHeader(request);
                    return next.handle(request);
                }));
        }
    }

    sleep(ms = 0) {
        return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));
    }
    getDefaultLanguage() {
        // const savedLanguage = this.storageSvc.retrieve('language');
        const savedLanguage = SingletonRootClass.getInstance().defaultLang;
        // Region code not used for now
        const language = { languageCode: savedLanguage ? savedLanguage : 'en', regionCode: 'CA' };
        return language;
    }

    buildAcceptLanguageHeader(languageCode, regionCode) {
        return languageCode + '-' + regionCode + ',' + languageCode + ';' + 'q=0.8,en;q=0.6';
    }
}
```

authService.ts :

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders  } from '@angular/common/http';
import { JwtHelperService } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';

import * as $ from 'jquery';

import { StorageSvc } from '../factories/storageSvc';
import { CrudService } from './crudService';
// import {NotifyHub} from '../../../src/app/angularJS-upgraded-providers';
import { SysSettings } from '../constant/sysSettings';
import { Authentication } from '../model/authentication.model';
import { SingletonRootClass } from '../../../src/app/shared/singleton-root';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    private serviceBase = SysSettings.WebServiceURL;
    private refreshInProgress = false;
    private refreshPromises = [];
    public authentication = new Authentication();

    constructor(
        private httpClient: HttpClient,
        private storageSvc: StorageSvc,
        private crudSvc: CrudService,
        private router: Router,
        // @Inject(NotifyHub) private notifyHub  //TODO
    ) {

    }


    refreshToken() {
        const authData = this.storageSvc.retrieve('authorizationData');
        const data = 'grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=' + authData['refreshToken'] +
            '&client_id=' + SysSettings.clientId;

        return this.httpClient.post(this.serviceBase + 'token', data,
            { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } }).pipe(tap((respData) => {
            const response: any = respData;
            const oldAuthData = this.storageSvc.retrieve('authorizationData');
            const loginTime = oldAuthData['loginTime'] ? new Date(oldAuthData['loginTime']) : new Date();
            const newAuthData = {
                token: response.access_token,
                userId: response.userName,
                userName: response.userName,
                refreshToken: response.refresh_token,
                useRefreshTokens: true,
                loginTime: loginTime
            };
            if (oldAuthData && oldAuthData['profile']) {
                newAuthData['profile'] = oldAuthData['profile'];
            }
            this.storageSvc.store('authorizationData', newAuthData);
        }));
    }

}
```